# gganimate object too large to render

Tags: r, ggplot2, gganimate

I've created a large gganim of a lorenz curve using packages
`ggplot2, gglorenz, gganimate, transformr and gifski`.
I've created the gganim plot using 'wealth_lorenz', a df of 5 variables and ~2.5 million rows using the below code,

`lorenz_chart <- ggplot(wealth_lorenz, aes(x = value, color = Limits)) + stat_lorenz() + transition_states(Time) + facet_wrap(~Limits)`

The gganim object created is 103.4MB in size.

Understandably, it takes too long to render in Rstudio using `animate(lorenz_chart)`.
Is there an alternative that could be faster to run out? I understand it's a very large dataset with faceting so it may not be possible. Ideally I'd like to include the animation in a bookdown PDF_2 using the animate package (see [here](https://gist.github.com/thomasp85/14ed997191f7c6d363517a4dd89f090b)) if possible.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: the question back is: why do you need to plot 2*10^6 data points? You might get very similar, if not better understandable results by summarising the data first, or by focussing on a limited range of the data. This will also reduce plotting and rendering time

Comment: @tjebo - fair question! To keep it as short as possible, the lorenz curve is used to show income inequality, and by sampling or summarising it in any way it can lose its demonstrative power. For example, if you were to take a random sample of 1000 people in the world and use their incomes to create a distribution, you'll probably be missing out the 0.0001% ( see here https://socialistworker.org/2015/11/04/the-rise-of-the-00001-percent) of incredibly high-earners who could have a large skewing effect. For my dataset there are a sporadic few very high earners that I can't leave out.

Comment: Fair point - however, this does not mean that you can't reduce the data! suggestions: 1) you could sample according to the expected distribution. 2) if you do "not so random sampling", e.g., if you take, say every forth data point, I strongly feel this should be equivalent to your data but like... a forth in size... etc :)

Comment: In the end, you're visualising in order to tell the story, and I am not sure if the story needs all the little details ... (but this is obviously the narrator's choice :)

Comment: And sorry for one more comment! This is actually more to the problem at hand. 1) I am not sure if I can reproduce your question - where is wealth_lorenz from? 2) Have you tried changing frames per second / resolution / time of running the animation ?

Comment: Hi @tjebo, sorry for taking a few days to get back to you - the data is from a particular distribution but could easily just be a very long vector of real numbers greater than zero. The problem here really is the length of the data and the need to capture all of it. To that end, the stat_lorenz() function is a very resource-intensive calculation (which needs repeated many times), so I decided to take another route by calculating the formula of each curve and then plotting as normal using geom_line() - I recommend anyone else using this function for large datasets do the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here really is the length of the data and the need to capture all of it. To that end, the stat_lorenz() function is a very resource-intensive calculation (which needs repeated many times), so I decided to take another route by calculating the formula of each curve and then plotting as normal using geom_line() - I recommend anyone else using this function for large datasets do the same.
Thanks.

Comment: Hello. I am using gganimate for the very first time and my large gganim object is 12.2 MB in size. Will that take a lot of time to render too?
(p.s. I'am using generativeart::generate_data which is creating around a df of around 400,000 points.)